# Self-similarity in ultrafilters over N

Tags: set-theory, filters

First, some notation:

- Set variables, $X, Y$, range over sets of natural numbers, $\mathbb{N}={1,2,3,..}$.
- Square brackets represent sets of natural numbers based on a formula.
  $$[φ(\mathbf{n})]=\{φ(n)|n∈N\}$$
  So, $[2n]=\{2,4,6…\}$ and $[\mathbf{n}^2] = {1, 4, 9, ..}$
- $X_Y$ = the selection of $X$ based on $Y$:
  $$X_Y = \{X_k|k\in Y\}$$ where $X_k$ is the $k$-th member of $X$ (in numeric order).

  So, $X_{[2n]}$ consists of every second element of X and $X_{[n^2]} = \{X_1, X_4, X_9,…\}$

Now, the question: Is there a non-principal ultrafilter, $F$, over $\mathbb{N}$ such that:

1. For each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $[k\mathbf{n}]\in F$.
2. If $X \in F$, then, for every $k$,
   $[k\mathbf{n}]_X \in F$.

Comment: How did you come up with the question?

Comment: I am trying to prove the existence of _sizings_ of sets of natural numbers which have satisfy some similarity conditions - for example - that $$\sigma(X) = \sigma(Y) \iff \sigma([kn]_X) =\sigma([kn]_Y)$$.  By _sizings_, I mean the kinds of orderings developed in the citations on my answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393/relative-sizes-of-sets-of-integers-and-rationals-revisited-how-do-i-make-sense/203828#203828.

Comment: @fmkatz, the answer also depends on the set axiom system: according to Herrlich's *Axiom of Choice*, in ZF+AD there are no non-principal (he calls them "free") ultrafilters on $\mathbb N$

Answer (score 7):

If I correctly understand your notation, the set $[kn]_X$ in requirement 2 is just $\{kx:x\in X\}$, so you are asking for the ultrafilter $F$ to be invariant under the operation $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ of multiplication by $k$ (for all $k$).  There is no ultrafilter that accomplishes this, even for a single $k>1$.  The reason is the theorem that, if an ultrafilter is mapped to itself by an operation $f$ on its underlying set, then the ultrafilter must contain the set of fixed-points of $f$.

For the particular operation you asked about, the (proof of) the general theorem can be specialized to the following.  Partition $\mathbb N$ into the set $X$ of those numbers whose binary expansion ends with an even number of 0's (i.e., odd numbers, numbers congruent to 4 mod 8, etc.) and the set $Y$ of numbers whose binary expansion end with an odd number of 0's (congruent to 2 mod 4, or to 8 mod 16, etc.) An ultrafilter $F$ must contain exactly one of these two sets.  But $[2n]_X=Y$ and $[2n]_Y=X$, so $F$ cannot satisfy your requirement 2.

Comment: I had a hunch that the Gravatar looks familiar! Welcome to math.SE!!

Comment: Welcome, indeed.  There is probably noone better suited to answer this question. But, perhaps I need to clarify the notation.

Comment: Sorry, I was going down the wrong path, there.  Do you have a reference for the general theorem about fixed points? Thanks.

Comment: How can $[2n]_Y=X$ if X contains the odd numbers? $[2n]_Z$ is always a subset of the even numbers.

Comment: Nice to see you here!

Comment: By the way, rather than $[2n]_Y=X$, it should say $[2n]_Y\subseteq X$. But this is all we need.