# There are more elements in the set $[-1,1]$ or in $[2,\infty]\cup [-\infty,-2]$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Recently I have found this problem:

> There are more elements in the set $[-1,1]$ or in $[2,\infty]\cup [-\infty,-2]$? Explain the reasons of your answer.

To be honest, I don't have completely any idea of how to approach this problem. I have found in Internet some videos (for example this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kf2Xwr22oGM), but I don't know if they can be useful to solve this problem. Any idea?

Comment: They have the same cardinality.

Comment: Hint: $x\mapsto x+\frac1x$ is a bijection between the sets $[-1,1]\setminus\{0\}$ and $(-\infty,-2]\cup[2,\infty)$.

Comment: The concept of "having the same size" for infinite sets is [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality). Some of the usual nice properties of the old concept do not apply anu more to infinite sets : a proper subset of an infinite sets may have the same cardinality of the "larger" one.

Answer (score 1):

When talking about the "size" of the set or which set has "more elements" in this context we are talking about the [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) of the sets.

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets.  We have the following nice property:

- $A\subseteq B \implies |A|\leq |B|$

Now... in the case that $A$ and $B$ both being finite, then $A\subsetneq B$ would have implied that $|A|\lneq |B|$, but that actually fails for infinite sets.  It is possible to have a proper subset of a set have the same cardinality as the larger set in question.  For example, [the set of even integers is of the same cardinality as the set of integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398/what-is-larger-the-set-of-all-positive-even-numbers-or-the-set-of-all-positi?noredirect=1&lq=1).

We also have the nice anti-symmetry property that we expect, that if $|B|\leq |A|$ and $|A|\leq |B|$, then $|A|=|B|$, the [cantor-schroder-bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem).  Also, equality of cardinalities is transitive, again as we expect (proven by showing that composition of bijections is again a bijection).

Next, relevant to talking about the real numbers we have that [any interval of real numbers has the same cardinality as the real numbers themselves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1434479/prove-any-open-interval-has-the-same-cardinality-of-bbb-r-without-using-tri?noredirect=1&lq=1).

There are many more nice properties about cardinality that I suggest you read up on, but these are the only things relevant here.

---

This all being said, you have $[-1,1]$ is a real interval and so has the cardinality of the real numbers.  You also have that $(-\infty,-2]\cup [2,\infty)$ is a superset of an interval of real numbers and so has cardinality at least as great as that of the real numbers, while also being a subset of the real numbers and so has cardinality at most that of the real numbers and so has the cardinality of the real numbers.

It follows then that $[-1,1]$ and $(-\infty,-2]\cup [2,\infty)$ are both sets with cardinality equal to the real numbers and so have the same cardinality as eachother.